# How can I use pyglet batches to draw scenes or levels

Tags: pyglet

So I'm currently learning pyglet for Python 2.7 and I'm trying to make a simple game that has levels. The 1st 'scene' would be the title/intro part, 2nd would be a tutorial of some sort, and the rest are the game levels themselves.

For this, I've created 7 batches(1 intro, 1 tutorial, 5 levels) namely batch, batch1, ... batch6. I've also created 7 classes for each of these batches that represent the scenes/levels. This is what I've done for the intro batch and class:

```
batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
batch1 = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
class StartState:
    def __init__(self):
        self.welcome = pyglet.text.Label('WELCOME TO', font_name='Arial', font_size=32, color=(200,255,255,255), x=400, y=550, anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center', batch=batch)
        self.title = pyglet.text.Label("MY GAME", font_name='Arial', font_size=32, color=(100,200,170,255), x=400, y=450, anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center', batch=batch)
        self.press = pyglet.text.Label("press 'SPACE' to continue", font_name='Arial', font_size=32, color=(200,255,150,255), x=400, y=250, anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center', batch=batch)
    def update(self, dt):
        if keymap[pyglet.window.key.SPACE]:
            self.welcome.delete()
            self.title.delete()
            self.press.delete()
            states.pop()
            batch1.draw()
```

The other scenes would also look like that. the states list is a list that I use to store my classes/scenes. states = [Level5(), Level4(), ... , TutorialState(), StartState()]. So every time the condition to advance is fulfilled, which in this class is to press 'SPACE', the window will be 'cleared' i.e. delete the sprites/labels and proceed to the next scene by using states.pop() and batch1.draw().

After I've typed these classes, I added this at the end:

```
@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    batch.draw()

def update(dt):
    if len(states):
        states[-1].update(dt)
    else:
        pyglet.app.exit()

states.append(Level5())
states.append(Level4())
states.append(Level3())
states.append(Level2())
states.append(Level1())
states.append(TutorialState())
states.append(StartState())


pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(update, 1.0/60.0)
window.clear()
window.flip()
window.set_visible(True)
pyglet.app.run()
```

The problem here is that it only loads the starting batch/scene. Whenever I press 'SPACE' to go to the tutorial scene the labels/sprites of the starting batch disappear but it doesn't draw batch1 or load the the tutorial class/scene. Any suggestions?

Comment: When handling the `on_draw` event, you only draw the Batch '`batch`'. Shouldn't it be overwritten with the batch corresponding to the 'state' you enter every time you press space? What about each of those state-classes having a field 'batch' and returning it in the 'update()' method, so you can assign it to the global batch you are drawing in `on_draw()`?

Answer (score 0):

After creating a batch for each scene class:

```
    import pyglet
    from pyglet.window import key

    class SceneTemplate(object):
        """a template with common things used by every scene"""
        def __init__(self, text):
            self.batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
            self.label = pyglet.text.Label(
                text,
                font_name='Arial', font_size=32,
                color=(200, 255, 255, 255), x=32, y=704,
                batch=self.batch)
            # (...)

    class MainMenuScene(SceneTemplate):
        def __init__(self):
            super(MainMenuScene, self).__init__(text='MainMenuScene')
            # (...)

    class IntroScene(SceneTemplate):
        def __init__(self):
            super(IntroScene, self).__init__(text='Introduction')
            # (...)

    class Level1(SceneTemplate):
        def __init__(self):
            super(Level1, self).__init__(text='Level 1')
            # (...)
```

You can control the state/scene in another class, such as a window class (personally I like to [subclass the pyglet window, to keep things organized and some other reasons](http://pyglet.readthedocs.org/en/latest/programming_guide/windowing.html#subclassing-window)):

```
    class Window(pyglet.window.Window):
        def __init__(self):
            super(Window, self).__init__(width=1024, height=768)
            self.states = [MainMenuScene(), IntroScene(), Level1()]  # and so on...
            self.current_state = 0  # later you change it to get the scene you want
            self.set_visible()

        def on_draw(self):
            self.clear()
            self.states[self.current_state].batch.draw()

        def on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers):
            if symbol == key.SPACE:
                new_state = self.current_state + 1
                new_state = new_state % len(self.states)
                self.current_state = new_state   
            # if you want each scene to handle input, you could use pyglet's push_handlers(), or even something like:
            #     self.states[self.current_state].on_key_press(symbol, modifiers)
            # giving them access to the window instance might be needed.

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        window = Window()
        pyglet.app.run()
```